# Cannot understand // in list comprehension

Tags: haskell

I'm reading a book called `Algorithms - Functional Programming Approach` by Fethi Rabhi and Guy Lapalme. I don't understand the part of code with syntax like `//`.

```
type Position = (Int,Int)
type Board = Array Int Position

mandist :: Position -> Position -> Int 
mandist (x1, y1) (x2, y2) = abs (x1-x2) + abs(y1-y2)

allMoves :: Board -> [Board]
allMoves b = [b//[(0,b!i),(i,b!0)]
    | i <- [1..8], mandist (b!0)(b!i) == 1]
```

Can't understand what `allMoves` is doing. Can someone explain me or turn this into list monad code with do notation?

Comment: see http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-Array.html#v:-47--47-

Comment: And in particular, [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%2F%2F) or [Hayoo `//`](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=%2F%2F). This is _not_ special syntax at all, just a custom-defined operator. If you encounter such symbols again, just ask the search engines!

Comment: can someone of you make this into an answer please?

Comment: to explain what this code does is hard because I do not (seem to) know the game - but it looks as if it will find you all *moves* in the following sense: there seem to be 9 *pieces* on the board and a valid move seems to be to swap the first piece with one that is adjacent to it. - `allMoves` will find all board configurations after such a swap happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`(//)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array/docs/Data-Array.html#v:-47--47-) is an operator from [Data.Array](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array/docs/Data-Array.html) (it's not some Haskell exotic syntax, just a regular infix function).

It looks like this: `(//) :: Ix i => Array i e -> [(i, e)] -> Array i e`
And this is the documentation for it:

> Constructs an array identical to the first argument except that it has
>   been updated by the associations in the right argument. For example,
>   if m is a 1-origin, n by n matrix, then
>
> `m//[((i,i), 0) | i <- [1..n]]` is the same matrix, except with the
>   diagonal zeroed.
>
> Repeated indices in the association list are handled as for array:
>   Haskell 2010 specifies that the resulting array is undefined (i.e.
>   bottom), but GHC's implementation uses the last association for each
>   index.